# How can I use a relationship in the with() method?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is `purchase_order` model:

```
class purchase_order extends Model
{
    protected $table = "purchase_order";

    public function commodities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(commodities::class, 'purchase_order_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

And here is `commodities` model:

```
class commodities extends Model
{
    protected $table = "commodities";

    public function scopeInvoiced($query){
        return $query->where('invoiced', 1);
    }

}
```

---

- `purchase_order::with('commodities')->get();` gives me all purchase_order with along their commodities.
- `commodities->invoiced()->get();` gives me all invoiced commodities.

Bow I need to get all purchase_order with along their **invoiced** commodities. How can I do that?

---

Neither of them work:

```
purchase_order::with(commodities::invoiced())->get();

purchase_order::commodities()->invoiced()->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) section of the documentation:

> ### Constraining Eager Loads
>
> Sometimes you may wish to eager load a relationship, but also specify
>   additional query constraints for the eager loading query. Here's an
>   example:
>
> ```php
> $users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
>     $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
> }])->get();
> ```
>
> In this example, Eloquent will only eager load posts where the post's
>   title column contains the word first. Of course, you may call other
>   query builder methods to further customize the eager loading
>   operation:
>
> ```php
> $users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
>     $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
> }])->get();
> ```

So, following this, try the code below:

```php
$purchase_orders = purchase_order::with(['commodities' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('invoiced', 1);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Yes it works well, thank you, upvote. Just why not adding `->where('invoiced', 1)` to the end of `return $this->hasMany(commodities::class, 'purchase_order_id', 'id')` in `commodities` method *(which is)* inside `purchase_order` class ?

Comment: Yeah, you could also do that, but notice this would constraint ALL the queries related to this relationship. If that is your use case go ahead :)